# How do I compare current date in jrxml file for jasper reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to compare date with current date but I am not getting how to represent current date in jrxml.
Code is something like this

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
    <![CDATA[ $F{dueDate} > [new java.util.Date()] ? "some value" : "some other value" ]]>
</textFieldExpression>
```

Can you please tell me correct representation of this code?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `before()` method in the `java.util.Date` class when comparing the two dates. The following example worked for me:

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[($P{date1}).before(new java.util.Date()) ? "aaa" : "bbb"]]></textFieldExpression>
```

If you want to check the value you get for new Date(), you can put it in a textfield and print it somewhere in your report.