# Date Validations in Jasper Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am working on a jasper report which takes two input date parameters from user as **START_DATE** and **END_DATE**.

I want to put validations on these dates like:

1) END_DATE should not be less than START_DATE
2) START_DATE should not be greater than END_DATE
3) END_DATE should be max upto 30 days after START_DATE (diff between START_DATE and END_DATE) should be max 30 days

I didn't get any way to do it using ireport. Does anyone know how to to it using ireport? Or is there any alternative way to achieve this in jasper server?

Comment: The iReport is just a GUI designer. You can not add validator to report's template

Answer (score 0):

I hope the third condition alone is enough. Also you can make use of variables to do such functionality.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403229/how-do-i-compare-current-date-in-jrxml-file-for-jasper-reports) would help you to go ahead.

Comment: The link that u have mentioned and my query are not related.

Comment: The link which I specified is just to get you started how to use the variables against parameter which has Date as datatype.